# How to allow more than 2 Mb limit with PHP on a shared hosting service?

Tags: php

by default PHP will not handle file uploads larger than 2MB, if one requires PHP to handle larger files then one must set upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini file to be larger than 2MB.

what alternative if one uses a shared hosting service with no access to php.ini ?

Comment: http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: Additionally: http://au.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Both of these options can be set with ini_set().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File uploads are handled before the script starts running so setting parameters with ini_set() will not work. All serious providers offer a way to customize your PHP settings. The exact mechanism should be explained in their help system and it depends on the server API:

- If PHP runs as Apache module, you can use the `php_value` and `php_flag` directives in an `.htaccess` file.
- If PHP runs as CGI (or FastCGI), you should have a custom `php.ini` file somewhere in your account.

Some of the settings you may need to change are (.htaccess version):

```
php_value max_execution_time 1200
php_value max_input_time 1200
php_value memory_limit 128M

php_value post_max_size 50M
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
```

Answer (score 3):

With [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) you can dynamically change PHP configuration.
But it is very possible that your provider will not allow you to do that.

Comment: All great, until you realise that this can't be changed on some hosts, no matter what you do.. and then you still have a limit.

Comment: Via manual: `Returns the old value on success, FALSE on failure.`

Answer (score 2):

hosting Control Panel, if any

.htaccess file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
```

but it can be restricted too.
anyway, such questions better to be addressed to the hosting support

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is a bit long winded, but will work.

You need to implement chunked uploads with a flash component handling the data transactions. Look into something like "[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com)" - although this particular plugin will not (as far as I know) do chunked uploads. Its a start, but you'll need to find a flash component that will do this, or get a flash developer to make one for you.

e: first try to set the upload limits directly using the methods described here, but if the host has locked this option, then above will be plan b =)

ee: found a component that does this - http://www.plupload.com/

Comment: seems great will try one day.